# Set up a javascript time to alert if page not refreshed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a site in production environment that reloads automatically every 3 mins. However, sometimes it gets stuck and does not update.

So I am looking for a small bit of javascript which will check the time since last page reload and if it exceeds 4 mins since last refresh then it will show me a alert that the page has not been updated since last 4 minutes or so.

Can I have a counter value which resets when page is reloaded and when if it exceeds a certain value say after 3 mins it gives a alert popup.

Can this be done?

Answer (score 1):

Your javascript code starts executing once a page is loaded. Write some function that will be executed once the page is loaded and set timer to 4 minutes which will generate the notification. If the page reloads than the timer won't reach it's time and no notification will be generated.

Read about timer [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.setInterval)

Comment: I need an idea how to set a timer in Javascript

Answer (score 1):

The final code for someone else if they require. Thanks for maximus help

```
    <script>
        function reloadCheck() {
             setInterval(function(){alert("Please Reload Page")},10000);
             }
    </script>
<body onload="reloadCheck()">
Checking page Reload
</body>
```